# Conditional Formatting in Excel 2010 of a cell that is within a certain percentage of another cell

Tags: excel, formatting

In Excel 2010 I am trying to conditionally format a cell depending on whether or not the value is less than, = to, or more than 5% of an adjacent cell. So if the value is over 5%, of another cell, this cell turns red and if 5% or under the cell turns green. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write any formula as a conditional format in Excel, as long as it can be evaluated to either true or false.

You can also use relative references to refer to cells in these formulas (they'll be relative to the top-left most cell in your conditional format's range)

[image: Excel Conditional Formatting Example]

Comment: Hi Josh thanks for your reply. Does your formula make all the B column follow these rules?

Comment: No, just the range specified in 'Applies to' i.e. B1:B3. I highly recommend doing a bit of reading on Conditional Formatting: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: In my excel sheet, A1 to A7 contain different values. e.g 10, 3.066, 5, 11.66, 3.2 and 2.5. Could you please provide an example using these figures?

Comment: The above example will work as the formula is using relative cell references. In conditional formats, relative cells references refer to the top-left most cell in the selected range. So in this example, the top-left most cell is B1 and this refers to cell A1, which is -1 columns 0 rows offset. Therefore, at B2, the conditional format will still look -1 columns and 0 rows offset, i.e. A2